# Using a variable that has a choose statement as a boolean

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

In XSLT 1.0, I'm creating a variable that has a choose statement within it.  The purpose for this would be handle logic once in a variable.  And then use the variable as a boolean downstream one or more times to control the logic flow.  The issue is that whether the logic within the variable evaluates to true() or false(), the variable always evaluates to true() in a test construct.

So, can I create a boolean variable in this manner?  And, if so, how should I do it and use it downstream?

My input XML is the following:

```
<root>
  <box id="435" type="A">keep</box>
  <box  id="872" type="A"></box>
  <box id="903" type="B">keep</box>
  <box id="1051" type="A">keep</box>
</root>
```

My expected result is the same:

```
<root>
  <box id="435" type="A">keep</box>
  <box  id="872" type="A"></box>
  <box id="903" type="B">keep</box>
  <box id="1051" type="A">keep</box>
</root>
```

But my actual result is:

```
<root>
  <box id="435" type="A">keep</box>

  <box id="903" type="B">keep</box>
  <box id="1051" type="A">keep</box>
</root>
```

My attempt at programming is:

```
<xsl:key name = "myKey" match="box" use="local-name()"/>

<xsl:variable name="allMustMatch" select="'true'"/>

<xsl:variable name="processFlag">
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="$allMustMatch = 'true'">
      <xsl:variable name="allCount" select="count(key('myKey', 'box'))"/>
      <xsl:variable name="typeCount" select="count(key('myKey', 'box')[not(@type = preceding::box/@type)]) + 1"/>
      <xsl:value-of select="$allCount = $typeCount"/>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
      <xsl:value-of select="true()"/>
    </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:template match="box">
  <xsl:choose>
    <!--  When $processFlag is false(), the following test evaluates to true().
          Also, when boolean($processFlag) is false(), the test evaluates to true(). 
          And when $processFlag is true() the test evaluates to true().
          How can I use $processFlag as a boolean? Or can I? -->
    <xsl:when test="boolean($processFlag)">
      <xsl:if test="normalize-space(.) != ''">
        <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
      </xsl:if>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

<!-- Identity template. -->
<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The XSLT specification provides two ways to define a variable (actually three, but we'll skip that for now):

---

The first way is using the `select` attribute. Here the variable will be bound directly to the selected object, and both its data type and its Boolean value will be that of the selected object.

For example, the data type of a variable defined as:

```
<xsl:variable name="myVar" select="1" />
```

will be *number* and its Boolean value will be *true* unless the number is 0 or NaN.

---

The data type of a variable defined as:

```
<xsl:variable name="myVar" select="1=0" />
```

will be *boolean* (and of course, its Boolean value will be *false*).

---

The data type of a variable defined as:

```
<xsl:variable name="myVar" select="/" />
```

will be a *node-set* and its Boolean value will be *true* unless the node-set is empty - for example, the Boolean value of:

```
<xsl:variable name="myVar" select="/.." />
```

will be *false* because the root node has no parent.

---

Note that defining a variable as you did:

```
<xsl:variable name="allMustMatch" select="'true'"/>
```

binds the variable to a *string*, and both this and:

```
<xsl:variable name="allMustMatch" select="'false'"/>
```

wil evaluate as *true* in a Boolean test, because any string with a non-zero length is evaluated as *true*. The correct way to hardcode a variable to a Boolean value would be:

```
<xsl:variable name="allMustMatch" select="true()"/>
```

or:

```
<xsl:variable name="allMustMatch" select="false()"/>
```

---

---

The other way to define a variable is by using a *template*.  This is necessary if, for example, you need to derive the value of the variable by using `xsl:choose` (as in your question). Here the data type of the variable will be a *result tree fragment* - and its Boolean value will be always *true*, regardless of the contents of the template. This is because the RTF is equivalent to a *node-set*, and it will always contain a root node, with the nodes produced by the template as child nodes - therefore it will never be empty.

So the answer to your question "can I create a boolean variable in this manner" is no (at least not in XSLT 1.0). The most you can do is something like:

```
<xsl:variable name="myVar">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$x=$y">1</xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>0</xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:variable>
```

and then, when you need to evaluate the variable as a Boolean, do:

```
<xsl:if test="number($myVar)">
```

---

However, I am not convinced you need such elaborate construct in your example. I am not sure I follow the required logic here, but you could probably do something like (untested):

```
<xsl:variable name="allMustMatch" select="true()"/>
<xsl:variable name="allCount" select="count(key('myKey', 'box'))"/>
<xsl:variable name="typeCount" select="count(key('myKey', 'box')[not(@type = preceding::box/@type)]) + 1"/>
<xsl:variable name="processFlag" select="$allCount=$typeCount or not($allMustMatch)"/>
```

Comment: Thank you @michael.hor257k  very much for your answer.  I wanted to make certain there was no way to create a boolean variable in the manner I described.  And I found your work arounds interesting.  I appreciate you help.

Comment: In your first example, surely the value of the variable is a result tree fragment, and converting a result tree fragment to a boolean always returns true? (Well, that's from memory, I haven't used version 1.0 for over 20 years). Converting the RTF to a number or string (rather than a boolean) is probably the best workaround.

Comment: @MichaelKay The variable is a RTF containing a text node. I am afraid I don't see how converting it to a number or a string would help. You *could*  change the subsequent test to `$test='true'`, though.

Comment: Well, if my memory serves me correctly (and this is ancient stuff!) converting an RTF to a boolean always gives true, whereas converting it to a number or string gives you something useful based on its actual content. So within the xsl:variable/xsl:choose you can set `<xsl:value-of select="0, 1"/>` and then test `boolean(number($var))`, or you can set `<xsl:value-of select="'', 'true'"/>` and test `boolean(string($rtf))`. Better still, move to a modern version of the language.

Comment: Sorry, I still have no clue what your point is. You seem to be suggesting the same thing as I did in my answer.

Comment: Sorry, I should have been clearer. You said 'The result here will be true. Why? Because the variable, as defined, contains a text node with the string-value of "true"'. But in fact the reason the result is true is that the `$test` variable is an RTF, and `boolean($test)` is therefore true regardless of the content of the RTF.

Comment: @MichaelKay  I see. You are right and I have revised my answer.